# Property of Dirichlet series which have $\sigma_{a}=1$

Tags: absolute-convergence, dirichlet-series

If the Dirichlet series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^s}
$$
converges absolutely for $\Re(s)>1$, does it follow that the Dirichlet series $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(n^2)}{n^s}
$$
also converges absolutely for $\Re(s)>1$ ?

It obviously holds when $f$ is bounded, and it also holds when $f(n)=\log(n)$. I'm unable to find a function $f$ that would not satisfy this property.

Can someone provide a counter-example?

Comment: Perhaps $f$ defined by $f(n)=0$ if $n$ is not a square, and $f(k^2)=k$ is an example ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is indeed a counter-example. If you want you can write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: no, I think it is clear as a comment, but thank you for the proposition...